# Both regular and small letters/symbols in equation mode

Tags: equations, small-caps

Hei guys!

So I am trying to figure out how to create a formula in equation mode with both regular and small letters. How do I accomplish this?

My code is this:

```
\begin{equation}
  \boxed{SS\begin{footnotesize}xy\end{footnotesize}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}(x\begin{footnotesize}k\end{footnotesize}-\Bar{x})(y\begin{footnotesize}k\end{footnotesize}-\Bar{y})}  
\end{equation}
```

The footnotesize command does not work, and neither does \small. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: no font size command is allowed (or needed) in math mode, what is the intended output here? don't you want `x_k` rather than `x\begin{footnotesize}k\end{footnotesize}` ???

Comment: what do you mean by regular and small letters?

Comment: `\footnotesize` is a text-mode command; it should *never* occur in math mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that by "small letters in equation mode", you mean letters in subscript or superscript position. If so, the following code may be what you're looking for.

[image]

Observe the use of `_` to initiate subscript mode and of `^` to initiate superscript mode. If the subscript or superscript material consists of a single letter (or numeral), it's not necessary to encase it in curly braces. Thus, `x_k` and `x_{k}` are entirely equivalent. Note also the use of `\mathit{SS}` instead of just `SS`, to space the two uppercase letters more closely.

A final suggestion: Do take the time to familiarize yourself with the basics of text *and* math mode coding in LaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for '\boxed' macro
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\boxed{\mathit{SS}_{xy}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}(x_k-\bar{x})(y_k-\bar{y}) }
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```